# MEF Importing assemblies in an imported assembly's constructor does not work - importing by calling a method does work?

Tags: c#, mef

I'm curious why the following happens:

When I use ImportMany in an imported assembly and call the compose method in the imported assembly's constructor, I can see that the ImportMany IEnumerable get's filled but as soon as I step out of the constructor and back in the parent assembly's code, move the mouse cursor over the just imported assembly it's ImportMany IENumerable is empty!

If I do the composing in a method which I call from the 'parent' assembly, everything work's fine.

Meaning the following does not work:
Example code (parent):

```
    private CompositionContainer modules;
    private AggregateCatalog catalogOfModules = new AggregateCatalog();
    #region MEF Imports
    [Import(typeof(IMyTypedInterface<someOtherInterface>),AllowDefault=true)]
    public someOtherInterface someObject;
    public void StartProgram()
    {
        try
        {
            catalogOfModules.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "directoryWichContainsMyAssembly"));
            modules = new CompositionContainer(catalogOfModules);
            modules.ComposeParts(this); 
            someObject.listOfModules.Count; # is 0              
        }
        catch (CompositionException)
        {
        }
    }
```

Example code (child):

```
[Export(typeof(IMyTypedInterface<someOtherInterface>))]
public class ExampleChild{
    [ImportMany(typeof(someInterface))]
    private IEnumerable<someInterface> listOfModules;
    private CompositionContainer modules;
    private AggregateCatalog catalogOfModules = new AggregateCatalog();
    public ExampleChild()
    {
        catalogOfModules.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "someDirectoryWithAssemblies"));
        modules = new CompositionContainer(catalogOfModules);
        modules.ComposeParts(this);
        listOfModules.Count; # is 2
    }
}
```

===========================================

but this does work

Example code (parent):

```
    private CompositionContainer modules;
    private AggregateCatalog catalogOfModules = new AggregateCatalog();
    #region MEF Imports
    [Import(typeof(IMyTypedInterface<someOtherInterface>),AllowDefault=true)]
    public someOtherInterface someObject;
    public void StartProgram()
    {
        try
        {
            catalogOfModules.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "directoryWichContainsMyAssembly"));
            modules = new CompositionContainer(catalogOfModules);
            modules.ComposeParts(this);     
            if (someObject != null)
            {
                someObject.ComposeMethod();
                someObject.listOfModules.Count; # is 2
            }
        }
        catch (CompositionException)
        {
        }
    }
```

Example code (child):

```
[Export(typeof(IMyTypedInterface<someOtherInterface>))]
public class ExampleChild : IMyTypedInterface<someOtherInterface>, someOtherInterface{
    [ImportMany(typeof(someInterface))]
    private IEnumerable<someInterface> listOfModules;
    private CompositionContainer modules;
    private AggregateCatalog catalogOfModules = new AggregateCatalog();
    public void ComposeMethod()
    {
        catalogOfModules.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "CM"));
        modules = new CompositionContainer(catalogOfModules);
        modules.ComposeParts(this);
        listOfModules.Count; # is 2
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me the reason for that behaviour?

Comment: Where is the ExportAttribute in the first version of ExampleChild? Without this MEF will not be able to import it. Also why do you have two different CompositionContainers? By the way IEnumerable has no Count property.

Comment: sorry forgot to paste it on here but it is in my real code. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was to call 'modules.ComposeParts' in every module that had sub-modules. Instead, just call the ComposeParts in the 'core'. Everything else is handled by MEF. So the code of the child becomes this:

```
[Export(typeof(IMyTypedInterface<someOtherInterface>))]
public class ExampleChild : IMyTypedInterface<someOtherInterface>, someOtherInterface
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(someInterface))]
    private IEnumerable<someInterface> listOfModules;        
}
```